# Inherited Activity methods are not being called from an imported library

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I'm trying to take my Java skills up a notch by learning to create a library of shared code/actives/components etc..

A couple of my apps all use the same *Login Screen Activity* and *UI* so I am trying to build a "Base Activity" class to inherit from in my TestApp so I can quickly reuse code.

When the application starts up the Login Screen is presented from the `BaseLoginActivity` but nothing in the `LoginActivity` is being called or overridden.

So when I click the login button `moveToDesiredIntent` is only called in the `BaseLoginActivity`.

All the "Base" classes are in the Library and my Child classes are in my TestApp.

I've read the Google docs on inheritance and I thought I was doing this correctly. 
I started with abstract BaseClasses but then I would get null pointers or not concrete classes.

**What is the proper way for me to inherit from my base classes so I can reuse code?**

---

### Code Below

I built a **BaseActivity** in my shared library

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Then I build the `BaseLoginActivity` in my library and in my test app a `LoginActivity` that inherits from that. The BaseLoginActitivy has a button with an onclick listener set

**BaseLoginActivity**

```
public class BaseLoginActivity extends BaseActivity{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.base_activity_login);
               Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:");
               Button button = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     moveToDesiredIntent();
                 }
                });

            }

            protected  void moveToDesiredIntent();
    }
```

**LoginActivity** THIS IS THE ACTIVITY THAT ISN'T GETTING ITS METHODS CALLED

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseLoginActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:"
    }

    @Override
    protected void moveToDesiredIntent() {
        super.moveToDesiredIntent();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

And finally, where you should go when you have logged in

**BaseDashboardActivity**

```
public class BaseDashboardActivity extends BaseActivity {
}
```

**DashboardActivity**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends BaseDashboardActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**Manifest of my TestApplication**

```
<application //...>
    <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">    
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
</application>
```

**Manifest of my Library**

```
<application //....>
    <activity android:name=".ui.base.BaseActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.shared.BaseLoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.shared.BaseOnBoardingActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Did you remove the `abstract` keyword from `moveToDesiredIntent`? Otherwise your code wont compile.

Comment: I did. I removed all the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `setContentView` in your `DashboardActivity`. If no layout gets inflated there is nothing to show. I would also suggest to make your base classes as abstract and provide abstract methods.

Comment: @murat-kI did have the Base classes abstract, but then I would get `NullPointersExceptions` Saying they needed to be in the Manifest. So I would add them to the manifest and then I got "classes are not concrete" errors. What would be the correct way?